# PC BSD 9 Port Problems

Tags: freebsd, bsd

I'm new to PC BSD and I've run into a few problems.  While updating my ports / installed ports, my computer's monitor will go black, then if I move the mouse the screen flickers.  If I restart the computer, x will not start up.  Does anyone know why this occurs?  I'll list the commands I execute.

```
#portsnap fetch extract
#portsnap update
//Says ports are all up-to-date

#cd /usr/ports/ports-mgnt/portmaster
#make install clean
#rehash
#pkg_version -l '<'
#portmaster -a
```

I'm using the Gnome interface with an nVidia card.  I have a few other issues I'd like to fix after this.  But I'll make another post after this.  Let me know if there's any other information I should provide.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like hardware trouble.

If you use a PCI(-e) graphics card, make sure it is plugged in properly. Also make sure that your CPU cooler is clean and its fan is working. Check the voltages of the power supply as well.

An overheating CPU or grahpics chip, or a dying power supply can cause all kinds of trouble.

Comment: I dont think that's the problem because I've reinstalled PC BSD on this machine multiple times and its always during the port updating process.

Comment: Make sure that it's not a problem with the graphics driver (e.g. failing to wake-up properly). You can test this by not starting X and running the port update from the console. If you're using the propretary driver, switch to nouveau and vice-versa. Also run a full `fsck_ffs` on your filesystems. FS corruption can crash the machine.